# Creating WaitConditionHandle using .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, ebextensions

I'm trying to create a `WaitConditionHandle` during the ElasticBeanstalk application deployment using AWS Elastic Beanstalk configuration files (`.ebextensions`).

The configuration file is in `yaml` and below is the content, created following [CloudFormation docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitconditionhandle.html):

```
Resources:
  ELBWaitConditionHandle:
   Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
   Properties:
```

While deploying the application, the ElasticBeanstalk is showing below error in events log:

> ERROR Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:[/Resources/ELBWaitConditionHandle/Properties] 'null' values are not allowed in templates

ElasticBeanstalk's CloudFormation stack is not updated, So it's failing the validation even before running stack update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the configuration from YAML to JSON resulted in below and explains the error I got:

```
{
  "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle",
  "Properties": null
}
```

So, I converted the [JSON syntax](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitconditionhandle.html#aws-resource-cloudformation-waitconditionhandle-syntax) given in AWS docs to YAML, which resulted in below:

```
Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
Properties: {}
```

With above, ElasticBeanstalk is creating WaitConditionHandle.